# Is it possible to use android phone as bluetooth headset for ps3?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bluetooth, audio, microphone, headset

Does anyone know how to use the android phone as a bluetooth headset so that i can use it as a mic while playing several games (COD) for example.

I'm using Ice Cream Sandwich and i have a Galaxy Vibrant. I don't want to buy a bluetooth headset so i'm simply looking to use my phone as an intermediate adapter. I can connect my wired headphones which has a mic attached to it.

Comment: Have a look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wo.voice&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS53by52b2ljZSJd) - absolutely no idea if it would work but it does look from the screenshots like it streams voice data over bluetooth

Comment: @Akash: See related post "How to make Android phone as a bluetooth headset?" from Stack Overflow for ideas relating to your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163453/how-to-make-android-phone-as-a-bluetooth-headset

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to an app that turns an Android phone into a more universal Bluetooth device, it is possible to control a PS3 with your Android phone as though it were a Bluetooth remote control. The connection allows the phone to be used as a virtual keyboard for entering text, and it even has a touchscreen trackpad for moving the cursor in the PS3's web browser.

The app, BlueputDroid, is in beta form right now, and is still a bit tricky to use, as the list of supported Android phones is not exhaustive, some of the phones require custom firmware and once you get the app installed, there are technical hoops to work through. A list of believed supported and unsupported devices can be found on [XDA-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=940511), where the app was introduced. It also has details on how to download the app for those who own a compatible Android handset.

The independent developer has tested it out on the Nexus One, HTC Wildfire, and LG Optimus One - all with rooted firmwares. He was not able to get it working on the Optimus One.

BlueputDroid is the first app to allow a smartphone to pair up with the PS3 as an input device. There have been other Bluetooth apps for Android that more flexibility in syncing the phone to a computer, but this is the first working app for PS3 connectivity. If the dev can further refine the process and expand compatibility, we'll welcome the chance to use our phones to input PSN info or type in URLs - beats having a real keyboard tethered to your system, hm?

source: http://www.gamesradar.com/how-to-use-your-android-phone-as-a-ps3-bluetooth-keyboard/

Comment: How exactly does this answer my question?

Answer (score 1):

Is your phone Rooted ? BlueputDroid works with rooted devices only (if you are prepared to root your device then this **maybe** achieveable with this app) according to this article entitled:
**How to remotely control your PS3 with Android BlueputDroid Apps Guide** written by *EHSAN* on Feb. 27th 2011.

http://topbestfreeapps.com/how-to-remotely-control-your-ps3-with-android-blueputdroid-apps-guide/

However checking the list of supported devices yours is not supported:

Unsupported devices
 ■Samsung Moment
 ■Samsung Galaxy Spica
 ■Samsung Galaxy S (this includes Captivate, **Vibrant**, Epic 4G, Fascinate, Showcase, Mesmerize, Continuum, K, U or any other variant of the Galaxy S series devices, but excluding Nexus S, which doesn’t have Samsung’s software, and which works!)
 ■Samsung Galaxy Tab
 ■HTC Eris
 ■HTC Incredible
 ■HTC Desire/HD
 ■HTC Desire Z
 ■HTC Legend
 ■HTC Hero
 ■HTC Magic
 ■HTC Evo 4G
 ■HTC Aria
 ■HTC/T-Mobile myTouch 4G

However this article was published in **early 2011**, almost two years ago, so maybe it is now supported.

The article does in theory provide partial insight into what you want to achieve !

I believe the article I mentioned in the comments above is more tailored to your needs however

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use it as a headset.

Just make your own app, and make its settings the same as the headset.

I made one for my LG P690F.

Comment: What kind of app will he make? Do you have a guide for it?

Comment: do you have a github link?

Answer (score -3):

Nope. Not possible. Only recognized or devices signed by Sony can be used for pairing with the PS3.

I don't think you can use ANY bluetooth headset. There are specific ones made for PS3.

Comment: This is incorrect, I have had no problems using a generic bluetooth headset with PS3.

Comment: @Rory if that is the case then it should be possible to use the phone as a generic bluetooth headset right? The app dint work for me :/

Comment: This answer is entirely wrong! The ps3 uses a bluetooth platform for their wireless devices, almost all bluetooth headsets work.... Unfortunately a select few dont work! There are not many people, that i know, toying around with android devices as a headset... There are people workung on the OP's problem, btw.

Comment: @AkashRamani, as an app dev it will depend on the version of android installed for the most part but the type of phone (i.e. Samsung HTC, LG... some may work others may not...) I just wanted to shed some light to a possible solution, and/or why it wont work... If you are rooted, upgrade to Android 4.3 or above to use the new BLE streategy google uses on all of their Android devices.