# WiFi Tablet makes Phone activate Hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, remote-control

Is there anyway to make a phone with android 4.3 automatically activate it's wifi hot spot at the request of a nearby android tablet.

For example, the tablet can message the phone via blue tooth to activate the phones WiFi Hotspot.

This is so that the user doesn't need to take the phone out of the pocket to activate the Hotspot before using the Internet on the tablet, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Multiple options, all involving [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker):

- Requires two things: [AutoRemote](http://www.appbrain.com/app/autoremote/com.joaomgcd.autoremote) and [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker). With that combination running on your phone, your tablet can request to enable the hotspot via... uh, internet. So this won't work if your tablet has no mobile data.
- So let's substitute *AutoRemote*: if your phone has NFC support, you could stick a NFC tag to your tablet, and use apps like [Trigger](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Trigger/com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher), [NFC ReTAG](http://www.appbrain.com/app/NFC-ReTAG-FREE/com.widgapp.NFC_ReTAG_FREE), again in conjunction with *Tasker*, to trigger the hotspot. Of course this would require NFC to be turned on.
- If BT is turned on on both devices, they are paired, and set to automatically connect: *Tasker* has a "state condition" registering when a BT connection is made (*Bluetooth Connected*). You can specify the device as parameter. So as soon as the two are "close enough", this could turn the Hotspot on. As this only recognizes when the connection is made, to "reverse" (i.e. turn the hotspot off), you'd rather use the *WiFi Connected* trigger (reversed, i.e. when your tablet is no longer connected).

Comment: Yes, I had looked into auto remote before realizing that it required Internet instead of allowing blue tooth. Regarding NFC, while it would require less work, it would still require extra work just to turn on hot spot.  While Bluetooth PAN Internet,  I actually had my Tasker automatically decide whether to connect to the blue tooth depending on whether the tablet was already connected to a wifi network, and running a Internet app.

Comment: Of course the problem is that the new phone no longer supports Bluetooth pan.

Comment: So I'm wondering if there is anything that can afford the same level of automation.

Comment: I've just added a third option to my answer, just requiring *Tasker* and Bluetooth. Maybe that would work for you?

Comment: Without PAN, Android phone has no other profiles to connect to.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then; though the answer to [Is it possible to use android phone as bluetooth headset for ps3?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22586/16575) suggests there might be something else "to connect to"...

Comment: If we're referring to the Bluetooth Devices > [Device] > Profiles List XXXX.

Under the Profiles list of my phone from my tablet, the list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

For example, those that are on earlier version of Android (possibility of it not working on Android 4.3)

There is an App called Keep In Pocket: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.KeepInPocket&hl=en

This lets you tether your tablet to your phone automatically. And as a bonus, you can see any SMS and Calls incoming from your phone, displayed on the Tablet.